# Как ограничить угол наклона объекта в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Допустим у меня есть поле, его можно будет наклонять, как мне ограничить угол наклона? Вот что я покамисть начудил. И да, вообще эту всю шнягу я хочу сделать под акселерометр, но тестю на мышке.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlaneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int xMax = 75;
    public int xMin = -75;
    public int zMax = 75;
    public int zMin = -75;

    public float gravity = -10;

    public float speed = 30000;
    public float tilt = 2;

    float horizontal;
    float vertical;
    bool mouseControl;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, gravity, 0);
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    horizontal = -Input.acceleration.x * speed;
    vertical = Input.acceleration.y * speed;

    Mathf.Clamp(horizontal, xMin, xMax);
    Mathf.Clamp(vertical, zMin, zMax);

    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(vertical, 0, horizontal) * Time.deltaTime;

    print("Horizontal: " + horizontal);
    print("Vertical: " + vertical);

    print("rotation X: " + GetComponent<Rigidbody>().transform.localEulerAngles.x);
    print("rotation Z: " + GetComponent<Rigidbody>().transform.localEulerAngles.z);
}
```

}

Comment: Ну, в целом можно и так. Только не совсем понятно зачем вы сразу результат расчета назначаете в наклон - там же сразу масса расчетов внутри юнити происходит. Создавайте временную переменную, потом делайте кламп её значений, а потом результат назначайте в transform

Comment: Ну если так как вы предложили, то шарик ужасно медленно котиться. А я хз что делать speed уже накрутил на 30000. Ща обновлю пост, кину полный код.

Comment: Вы умножаете на скорость не там. Сначала клампите, а потом там же, где умножаете на Time.deltaTime умножайте и на скорость. А то вы умножаете на 30000, а потом клампите между -75 и 75) вот и получаете максимум столько.